# Retouching syntax highlight of major mode

Tags: faces, font-lock, colors, haskell-mode

I am writing a minor mode to complement `haskell-mode`,
and I am trying to color subwords in **camel**Cased identifiers with slightly different shades of the same color.

Perhaps this can be done by "recoloring" identifiers, that is, running a hook which redefines the font-locking after the major mode does its work.

But I have no idea how this can be achieved.

Any ideas or references are very welcome!

**Edit:** @phil's suggestion is working for me, so in the interest of saving time, I am leaving the minor-mode project on hold for now.

Comment: Not a solution, but does `glasses-mode` work in haskell-mode?  If so, that may provide some insight into targeting camelCase words.

Comment: Indeed! Good enough for now (using Letter Low Vertical Line Unicode Character U+02CC as the separator).